# How to use the ColdFusion session in java application running in same Tomcat 8 server?

Tags: java, coldfusion, session-variables

I have a ColdFusion application war, and a Java application war, deployed in same Tomcat 8 server. I have a valid ColdFusion session and wanted to get access to that session in java. How can I do that?
Since  I am new to ColdFusion, I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't know, so I googled `access coldfusion session from java`.  That led me to [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-web-elements-and-external-objects/integrating-jee-and-java-elements-in-cfml-applications/interoperating-with-jsp-pages-and-servlets.html), which says:

> Similarly, the ColdFusion Session scope is a structure within the JEE
>   session (*assuming that the J2EE Sessions feature has been enabled, as
>   discussed in the next session*.) Because ColdFusion identifies sessions
>   by the application name. the session structure is contained in an
>   attribute of the JEE session that the application name identifies.
>   Therefore, you access ColdFusion session variables as follows:
>
> `((Map)(session.getAttribute("CFApplicationName"))).get("sessionVarName")`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have tried the above in my spring java application but the CFApplicationName doesnt exist in the session.

Comment: Did you follow this part of the link? *To share session variables, specify J2EE session management in the ColdFusion Administrator.*

Comment: "CFApplicationName" is just the placeholder. You need to replace that with the actual ColdFusion application name. The application name is either in `<cfapplication name="...">` (when using `Application.cfm`) or `this.name = "..."` (when using `Application.cfc`).